# Можно ли как-то сделать универсальный геттер(сеттер) для всех полей класса?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, visual-c++, инкапсуляция

У меня есть класс, в котором достаточно большое количество полей (допустим, >30). В книгах пишут, что для обеспечения истинной инкапсуляции все члены класса должны быть приватными (либо протектед), а доступ к ним через геттеры и сеттеры. Так вот, при таком большом количестве полей количество методов, обеспечивающих доступ к полям, будет > 60 (хоть они и однострочные, но всё же).
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать это красиво, функционально и профессионально? (может быть шаблоны и пр.) Сразу условлюсь, что количество полей уменьшить, допустим, не вариант.
Всем спасибо!

Comment: Я бы использовал макросы, здесь они к месту. Но! Такое количество полей говорит о вероятно плохом дизайне.... Вам точно они все нужны и именно вот так, в одном классе?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Никак их не уменьшить. Кодогенерации и рефлексии в С++ нет.

Comment: @Harry , на самом деле - нужны. Если Вам интересно, в данном случае это класс с летными характеристиками воздушного судна. Перечень данных характеристик достаточно обширен. Спасибо!

Comment: Ваять геттеры и сеттеры просто из любви к искусству — тоже вариант не очень веселый. Может, подумать о том, чтоб собрать все эти данные в структуру с открытыми полями? Это тоже вполне допустимый вариант.

Comment: ох ох этот "ООП" подход. Да не нужно создавать геттеры и сеттеры на каждое "поле" (переменную класса). Если они только то и делают, что просто меняют ее, то смысла в них никакого (ну кроме настоящий любителей единственно правильного ООП). Скорее всего эти все данные можно разделить на логические группы. А там и классы будут меньше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот как вариант — с применением макросов, примерно

```
#define  DEF_GETSET(type, name) \
    private: type name; \
    public:  type get_##name() { return name; } \
             void set_##name(type val) { name = val; }
```

Это, понятно, если типы полей простые, и геттеры/сеттеры такие же. Более сложные вещи так не сделаешь, там ручная индивидуальная работа :)

Тогда класс определяется просто, наподобие

```
class Test
{
    DEF_GETSET(int, i)
    DEF_GETSET(int, j)
    DEF_GETSET(char, c)
};
```

Ну, а работать с методами типа `get_@@@` и `set_@@@`, что-то вроде:

```
int main()
{
    Test t;
    t.set_i(5);
    cout << t.get_i();
}
```

Но дизайн с 30 полями мне *очень* не нравится. Тот самый "code smell", который говорит о том, что пора приступить к рефакторингу :)

Создавать геттеры и сеттеры просто из любви к искусству (потому что так написано в учебнике :)) — тоже вариант не самый веселый. Может, вам ст*о*ит подумать о том, чтоб собрать все эти данные в структуру с *открытыми* полями? Это тоже вполне допустимый вариант. Делать что-то просто потому, что "так положено" — не стоит, всегда надо учитывать конкретные обстоятельства...

Comment: Благодарю за советы. :)

Answer (score 0):

Если точно не подходит ни разбивка на меньшие классы (что просится если не всвязи с Single Responsibility Principle, то хотя бы для более структурированного кода), ни использование публичных членов-данных (которое просится, т.к. если геттеры/сеттеры тривиальные, то, значит, никакой инвариант класса они не защищают), то остаётся взять и написать эту сотню геттеров. Ну можно отсортировать по алфавиту или логически и/или выровнять табличкой :-)

Кодогенерация с помощью препроцессора -- сомнительная идея:

- мешает удобству отладки
- сводит с ума некоторые инструменты IDE
- усложняет чтение кода

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Препроцессор и кодогенерация - это все-таки разные вещи.

Answer (score 0):

> У меня есть класс, в котором достаточно большое количество полей (допустим, >30). В книгах пишут, что для обеспечения истинной инкапсуляции все члены класса должны быть приватными (либо протектед), а доступ к ним через геттеры и сеттеры.

Пишут там либо неправильно, либо вы неправильно поняли. Если вы к полю класса напишите сеттер и геттер, то это эквивалетно тому, что вы сделали поле открытым. В ООП вообще классы должны разрабатываться не исходя из полей, а поведения класса. То есть у класса определяется открытый интерфейс - методы, а затем для имплементации этого итерфейса пишутся внутренние поля, причем это внутреннее дело класса, какие поля у него есть или нету. Согласитесь при таком подходе у вас не будет геттеров и сеттеров, у вас интерфейс класса будет первичным.

А если вы каждому полю автоматически генерируете геттер и сеттер, то проше сделать все поля `public:` это ничего не изменит, только создаст видимость инкапсуляции.